# Can you help me improve this circuit design?

Tags: zener, bus, protocol

I'm a electronic noobie and for a school project I need to design a circuit that will then be connected to a micro controller. The aim of the project is to build a sniffer to decode a particular protocol. So the circuit will have to convert DC voltage values to logical values that the micro-controller will then read to decode and print the frames flowing through the bus, on a terminal for example. So I began by creating a circuit that will be able to convert the voltage values of the protocol into logical values:

- Forward frames : 15V for high level and 4V for low level
- Backward frames : 4V for high level and 2V for low level

4V being the idle state. The circuit I designed look like this

[image]

The Vcc supply of the micro controller is 2.8V. I decided to use 2 pins for Rx, one for the Forward frames (ADR_COMM on the schematic) and one for the backward  frames (ADR_REP). According to the simulation on LTspice, ADR_COMM is high when voltage is 15V and low otherwise, and ADR_REP is high when voltage is 4V and low otherwise so I get what I want.

Initially I used a zener diode with a breakdown voltage of 3V instead of the R6 resistor to prevent the 2V from turning on the U1 photo coupler but the current dropped to 1 mA (instead of 40mA) when using it. So my first question is why ?

Also I would like to know if there is anyway of improving this circuit, any good practice that I should know about or tips ?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you having any problems with the circuit which may motivate others to take time to help solve?

Comment: We discourage broad, open-ended design review questions here on EE.SE, because the answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" on the meta site.

Comment: You probably want to go learn about *comparators*. Using these very common ICs will probably simplify your circuit dramatically.

Comment: Maybe not a circuit design tip, but a schematic readability tip; use 'net' nodes to reduce schematic complexity. V2 and V3 are presumably both Vcc, but you didn't want to clutter the schematic by combining them. Using nets you could label a node as Vcc and then 'attach' it to where you want Vcc, rather than create a whole new voltage source.

Comment: Seconding photons comment. You should re-design this using comparators. It will be much simpler and behave in a more predicable way. You could include a few pots to adjust the voltage thresholds.

Comment: Or depending on the baud rate of your signal, you might just use and adc and get rid of the whole circuit.

Comment: Why are you using optocouplers instead of just using npn transistors? I’m guessing that you want the three different sources to have isolated grounds from one another.

Comment: @rr1303, except there are other connections between the sources besides ground.

Comment: Is all this just a "level shifter"?

Comment: Thank you for all your feedback. I will try to re-desingn it using comparators but I still do have a question though, It may be very basic stuff but I don't understand why the current drop to 0mA instead of 50 mA  when I'm using a zener diode with a breakdown voltage of 3V instead of a resistor, with a 4V as input